# haskell convert a list of custom data to a list of chars?

Tags: haskell

Hi i'm very new to haskell, I've been working on a simple tic tac toe game. I'm wondering if theres a way to convert my list of custom data into a list of chars.

```
module TicTacToe where

import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split
import System.Console.ANSI

type Board = [[Space]]
type Space =  Maybe Player

data Player = PlayerX | PlayerO deriving (Eq, Show)
data State = Running | GameOver (Maybe Player) deriving (Eq, Show)
data Game = Game { gameBoard :: Board
                 , gamePlayer :: Player
                 , gameState :: State
                 } deriving (Eq, Show)

initialGame = Game { gameBoard = initialBoard
                   , gamePlayer = PlayerX
                   , gameState = Running
                   }

initialBoard = [ [Nothing, Nothing, Nothing]
               , [Nothing, Nothing, Nothing]
               , [Nothing, Nothing, Nothing]
               ]

printBoard = print . gameBoard  

updateBoard :: Game -> Int -> Space -> Game -- updates the game board
updateBoard game i s = if (i < 1 || i > 9) 
                            then game 
                            else do
    let b = concat $ gameBoard game
    let (x,y:ys) = splitAt (i - 1) b
    let b2 = if y == Nothing -- if the space equals Nothing
        then x ++ [s] ++ ys -- then we will allow a PlayerX or PlayerO to be placed
        else b               -- otherwise b2 will equal the game board we started with   

    let b3 = chunksOf 3 b2
    game { gameBoard = b3 }


switchPlayer :: Game -> Game -- switches the player
switchPlayer game = 
    case gamePlayer game of
    PlayerX -> game { gamePlayer = PlayerO }
    playerO -> game { gamePlayer = PlayerX }   

gameLoop :: Game -> IO ()
gameLoop game = do
    putStrLn "Enter a Number 1-9"
    playerMove <- getLine
    clearScreen
    let newGame = updateBoard game (read playerMove :: Int) (Just (gamePlayer game))
    let checkGame = if (newGame == game)                     -- If the updated game is equal to the old game
                        then gameLoop newGame                -- then we restart the loop with no changes
                        else gameLoop $ switchPlayer newGame -- otherwise we restart the loop and switch the player

    printBoard newGame -- print the game board
    checkGame

main = gameLoop initialGame
```

basically I would like to take my gameBoard and instead of being displayed as `[[Just PlayerX, Just PlayerO, Nothing], [Nothing Nothing, Nothing], [Nothing, Nothing, Nothing]]`

I would instead like it to be displayed as:

```
[['X', 'O', "."]
,['.', '.', '.']
,['.', '.', '.']
]
```

Comment: You can just write your own instance of `Show` for the `Game` type, rather than relying on the derived one. It's probably best to start with a custom `Show` instance for `Space` and work up from there - but you'd have to make `Space` a `newtype` rather than just a type synonym.

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: Apologies, I had to get ready for work (had just woken up when I first posted). I will attempt to write something up now, but I just realised my first comment was innacurate - I meant the `Board` type, not `Game`. Also, having had a slightly closer look through your code, are you sure this compiles and works? [I'm  unable to test while I'm work.] I'm referring to the use of `do` notation in `updateBoard` - `Game` isn't a monad so I don't see how this could ever work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your board displaying in the way you want, I would start by replacing this:

```
type Space =  Maybe Player
```

with this:

```
newtype Space = Space {unSpace :: Maybe Player} deriving (Eq)
```

This makes `Space` in to an entirely different type from `Maybe Player`, as far as the compiler is concerned (although it is treated the same at runtime), which means you can give it a new instance for any of the standard typeclasses. You can see I've derived `Eq` because that instance is going to be needed - but we want to give it a custom instance of `Show` to display the `X` or `O` (or empty space) that you want to see. And this is dead easy to do:

```
instance Show Space where
    show (Space (Just PlayerX)) = "X"
    show (Space (Just PlayerO)) = "O"
    show (Space Nothing) = "."
```

I should point out though that making `Space` into a `newtype` rather than a mere type synonym will necessitate changing any of your code where the `Space` type is used, and in an a slightly boilerplate-ish way. I only spot one case of this in your existing code though (although I could have missed some), in `updateBoard` where you have `x ++ [s] ++ ys`, you will need to change it to `x ++ [Space s] ++ ys`. [Basically all you'll ever have to do is add calls to `Space` and `unSpace` in appropriate places, to convert between the two equivalent types.]

Making this change won't take you all the way to what you want, because it will still print all 3 rows of the board on one line. But then you can do the same with `Board`.

Replace

```
type Board = [[Space]]
```

with

```
newtype Board = Board {unBoard :: [[Space]]} deriving (Eq)
```

(This will likely also add the need for calls to `Board` and `unBoard` throughout your code.)

Then put:

```
instance Show Board where
    show (Board rows) = intercalate "\n" $ map show rows
```

Compared to the standard instance for a list, this drops the outer `[..]`, and replaces the `,` between each row with a newline character. I believe this will give you what you want - at the expense, as I said, of a little boilerplate here and there.

Please note that I'm unable to check this myself at the moment, so apologies if I've overlooked something and this fails to compile or otherwise fails to work (and let me know so I can correct it).

Comment: thank you, after a few ajustments and some trial and error i got it working how i would like!

Comment: I think this answer would be improved by the usual warning about custom Show instances that are not round-trippable via Read. Instead of repurposing Show, this custom display would be more easily achieved with an ordinary function.

Comment: Hi @amalloy, I appreciate the response. I'm pretty new to Haskell and know I have a lot to learn, so I don't know about this "usual warning". I do see that in many cases you would want `show` and `read` to be inverses of each other, but it's not clear here that one would ever need to use `read` on a `Board`. And the `newtype` still allows one to choose which `Show` instance to use, by deciding whether or not to use the "wrapped" version. My concern with my approach is that it involves some boilerplate, and a custom function may be better. Chepner has already suggested that in his answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The less "structured" version of Robin Zigmond's answer just recognizes that as long as you have a function of type `Space -> Char`, you just need to map it *twice* over your board.

```
showSpace :: Space -> Char
showSpace (Just PlayerX) = 'X'
showSpace (Just PlayerO) = 'O'
showSpace Nothing = '.'

showBoard :: Board -> [String]
showBoard = map (map showSpace)
```

Then

```
let b = [[Just PlayerX,Just PlayerO,Nothing]
        ,[Nothing,Nothing,Nothing]
        ,[Nothing,Nothing,Nothing]
        ]
in showBoard b == ["XO.", "...", "..."]
```

In fact, `showSpace` itself can be defined using the `Maybe` functor (though most simply by way of the helper function `maybe`):

```
showPlayer :: Player -> Char
showPlayer PlayerX = 'X'
showPlayer PlayerO = 'O'

showSpace :: Space -> Char
showSpace = maybe '.' showPlayer
```

The role of the `Show` typeclass is simply to let you define all the various functions for `Player`, `Space`, `Board`, etc under the single name `show` instead of having different names for each.